# Magento Shipping costs

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

is there an way, that the cart calculate the total weight and multiply with the highest product rate for example if i have 6 items of ShiptypeA and 4 items of ShiptypeB = 21.99 Euro by the ShiptypeB  rule for 5 kg ?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please specify your magento version you are facing issue with.

Comment: i use magento version 1.9